# Fitting data to an exponential model with a specified rate in R

Tags: r, exponential-distribution, density-estimation

I have been using the fitdistr package in R to try and do this but with no luck so far:

```r
fit1 <- fitdistr(data1$x, "exponential", start = list(rate = 10))
```

I am getting this error:

```r
"Error in fitdistr(data1$x, "exponential", start = list(rate = 10)) : 
  supplying pars for the exponential distribution is not supported"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the error suggests, you don't use `start` variable. Example usage for the exponential case:

```
fit1 <- fitdistr(data$mns, "exponential")
```

You can see from [here](https://github.com/cran/MASS/blob/master/R/fitdistr.R#L103) that it just uses ML estimator.

Comment: +1 for pointing out the src code!

Comment: I don't want the parameter that it uses to be the ML estimator.

Comment: If you want the parameter to be equal to what you want, it's not called fitting. Just plot exponential PDF over your data and see if it really fits in then.

Comment: @gunes I just realised this haha, thanks for the answer

Comment: @43zombiegit you're welcome. If you think the answer (or the other answers) is ok, can you please accept/upvote it?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to fit a model, then the parameter is calculated by the fitting process. Why are you specifying the rate to be fit?

In many cases, we do not need to specify anything to do the fit. Think about the fit for OLS model, we do not need to specify where to start. The fitting algorithm will pick a random starting point and get the optimal value for the parameter.

Comment: I want to specify the parameter beforehand, not leave it up to R to decide using an MLE

Comment: Then you're not fitting any distribution @43zombiegit

Answer (score 0):

The error message states exactly what the problem is. Why not just run:

```r
MASS::fitdistr(rexp(100000), "exponential")
#      rate    
#  0.998885118 
# (0.003158752)
```

Comment: I tried that earlier but I need the parameter for the rate to be equal to 10. The reason is that I then fit the model again but with a different parameter and will go on to perform a likelihood ratio test with both of the models that have different rates.

Comment: You want to do maximum likelihood estimation... with a fixed parameter value?